# Time stamp in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I am using `plainnat` style while using `natbib` package with `number` option. I want `timestamp` to appear in the bibliography. Even though it's in the bib file, it's still not appearing.

bib:

```
@Misc{example,
  author    = {Dr. Example},
  title     = {A motivating example},
  year      = {2015},
  journal   = {English news},
  language  = {English},
  timestamp = {2016-09-15},
  url       = {www.stackexchange.com},
}
```

This is show it's appearing

```
[5] Dr. Example. A motivating example, 2015. URL http://www.stackexchange.com.
```

Comment: The basic idea of a `.bib` file is that you can add any fields you want to a given entry, and it is up to the `.bst` to typeset them otherwise they will be ignored. (This is a great feature. I often include library call number fields in entries without worrying that such information will show up in the output unless I *make* it show up.) So for timestamps, your options are: (1) use a `bibliographystyle` or `.bst` that recognizes the field; (2) hack an existing style so it recongizes the field; or (3) put the timestamp in a field that will be printed (e.g., `note`).

Comment: The simple hack seems to work, is there a format to write the timestamp "Accessed: 21-11-2016". I mean the word "Accessed", or i just write the date?

Comment: Off-topic: Fir entries of type `@misc`, the `plainnat ` style won't output the contents of the `journal` and `language` fields either...

Comment: @Mico, Thanks, yes i realized it. Can you please tell me how to write the timestamp. is it "Accessed: dd-mm-yyyy" or just "dd-mm-yyyy". I am just writing the timestamp in the notes as suggested by jon

Comment: @Aashu10  - I wouldn't hack the bibliography style file to make it recognize a field named `timestamp`. Instead, I would (a) change the name of the field from `timestamp` to `note` and (b) insert a phrase such as "Last accessed on" at the beginning of the field. The exact day-month-year  format will depend on style conventions practiced by you and/or the journal you are planning to submit the paper to.

Comment: The field `timestamp` is used by JabRef to show when you added that reference to your own bib library. So, I guess it's not a field that should be published. It's only for your own organization. http://help.jabref.org/en/TimeStamp